# How to perform segue depending on string in table?

Tags: ios, xcode4.6

I have a query; I have a dynamically populated table which contains strings. It has a search function attached, how can I perform a segue depending on the selected string/cell?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem some time ago and this piece of code really helped me out.

I am assuming that you have your search function fully functional.

It is all based around an else if statement.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellcontent = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

    if ([cellcontent isEqualToString:"CellOne"]) [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CellOne" sender:self];
    else if ([cellcontent isEqualToString:"CellTwo"]) [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CellTwo" sender:self];        
}
```

}

You will probably notice that this only caters for segues from the search RESULTS table. You need a very similar piece of code for your none-results table. I'm sure you can figure that little change out.

Let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the appropriate delegate method and assert the cell's textLabel text. Perform the appropriate segue...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"SomeText"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:cell];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys!

I managed to get the appropriate segues from the search results from playing with the code examples you've give me.